# Authentication users with different role same Guard Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-blade, roles, guard

I am using two different guard in laravel: 'admin' and 'web', for admin I have users with two different roles ('administrador' and 'tecnico'). I would like to check the role name for users authenticated as admin, but I should have a mistake as it only works when I use the role_id and no the role name (both are attributes in Role Table, id (pk)).

This setence works:

```
@if( Auth::guard('admin')->user()->role_id=="1") ... @endif
```

This setence doesn't works properly:

```
 @if( Auth::guard('admin')->user()->role-name="administrador") ... @endif.
 @if( Auth::guard('admin')->user()->role->name="tecnico") ... @endif.
```

I have already print all the setences and they have the correct attributes values, I guess that laravel only checks that they are authenticated as guard, but when I use the id number it actually let me control accordingly to the user role who is login.

Answer (score 1):

I think its syntax error. Only = is the assignment operator.Use == for match role

```
@if( Auth::guard('admin')->user()->role->name=="administrador") ... @endif.
@if( Auth::guard('admin')->user()->role->name=="tecnico") ... @endif.
```

I guess below sentence work perfectly because `role_id` is also present in the users table

```
@if( Auth::guard('admin')->user()->role_id=="1") ... @endif
```

Hope this work